# I don't like [you to go there]

Tags: infinitives, gerund-vs-infinitive

> 1. I don’t like you **going** there.
> 2. I don’t like you **to go** there.

*Like* can take both *-ing* and a to-infinitive as complement. But can the expression that the matrix subject and the subject of to-infinitive are different, as (2), be used? [OALD](http://www.oxford) says “We'd like **you to come** and visit us” is possible. But I’m not sure if (2) is possible.

---

added samples after consulting Angela Downing's English Grammar, BNC, and COCA:

> And her mother did not like **her to be out** for too long. (Angela Downing, English Grammar, from BNC)
>   He did not like **her to leave** his side for more than a day. (T S Eliot. Ackroyd, Peter. London, from BNC) 
>   Christina did not like **them to receive** such a bad impression of Crystal Springs. (BNC) 
>   she did not like you to call them geraniums! (BNC) 
>   However, schools did not like **students to feel** at home in arts and science. (BNC) 
>   Mrs Mantini did not like **Rachaela to sit and read** in the shop. (BNC) 
>   Dear mamma did not like **me to use** them. (COCA) 
>   David McCutcheon talked with therapists about the one thing he did not like **women to do**. (COCA) 
>   We did not like **them to run** free, leaving us at the mercy of their floods. (COCA) 
>   Dad did not like **kids to touch** his desk. (COCA) 
>   The woman did not like **him to speak** of dying, death, burial. (COCA)

Comment: 2 is pretty unnatural, but "I don't want you to go there" is fine.

Comment: In the OALD example *like* is used as *want* but *don't like* means something different than *don't want,* So you need to use: "I don't want you to go there.   For (2) some people may say, "I don't like **for** you to go there." but (1) is preferable.

Comment: @Jim, I've found 'didn't like somebody to do' constructions from three places. Does it mean the construction is used not often but not rarely?

Comment: BTW, "I don’t like **you** going there." and "I don’t like **your** going there." are very different in focus and even in meaning.

Comment: possible duplicate of [“I like to do (be) something” vs “I like doing (being) something”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21498/i-like-to-do-be-something-vs-i-like-doing-being-something). Related: [Why “like doing something” or “like to do something” but only “dislike doing something”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/173035/)